# Enable GPS setting in Android

Tags: android, gps, location

I have set up googleMaps in my Application and I want to create an alert box in case the user does not have his/her GPS enabled.

I have everything set up properly but I think I have problem with the following function:

```
private void launchGPSOptions() {
    final ComponentName toLaunch = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.SecuritySettings");
    final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    intent.setComponent(toLaunch);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

The case which I encounter is that when I have not my GPS enabled and then I press the button for finding my Location instead of dropping me into the GPS settings, is dropping me in the Security settings. I think the fault is the second argument of ComponentName.

Can someone help me finding the right class name for the GPS ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a common class and access this method, as you will require this method to call in multiple places.

```
public static void showGpsSettings(Context context){
        Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use this  `startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));`

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
          startActivity(intent);